# Migrating vs2008 to vs2012 - Exception LINQ to SQL Library

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I am relatively new to Visual Studio and I figured the best way to proceed would be to [sarcasm] do a major project [\sarcasm].

**Summary of work to be done here:**
VS2008                       ->  VS2012 
Windows7                     ->  Windows8 
SQL CompactServer v3.5       ->  SQL CompactServer v4.0 
.NET Framework v2.0          ->  .NET Framework v4.0

One of the problems I am running into is that even though I have migrated my DB file in VS from SQL_CE_v3.5 to SQL_CE_v4.0 and updated my references to System.Data.SqlServerCe (4.0), I am getting the following exception when an attempt to open the db file is made the following way.

```
DB.DataContext = new DB.DataContext(CONNECTION_STRING);
```

**Exception:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open '|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf'. Provider 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5' not installed.
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Initialize(IDataServices dataServices, Object connection)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Init(Object connection, MappingSource mapping)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrServerOrConnection, MappingSource mapping)
.
.
.<br>
```

**Question:** 
How can I change the provider name here to 4.0 instead of 3.5?
What would be the best way to do all these migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialze the DataContext object with a SqlCeConnection object, not a connection string, so something like:

```
DB.DataContext = new DB.DataContext(new SqlCeConnection(CONNECTION_STRING));
```

Comment: That worked!!...Thanks a lot!! Help me understand here...If a CONNECTION_STRING is passed directly, the LINQ libraries attempt to open them using the tool they were generated from i.e a CE3.5 db?  PS. What is this talk about VS2012 not supporting LINQ anymore?

Comment: If you supply a connection string, and it is parsed not to be a Server connection string, it is hard coded to use the 3,5 provider.

Comment: Got it.... Thank you for your help on this...I spent a considerable amount of time in figuring this out....